# Does Postgresql apply the same type of locks on UPDATE with range condition and on UPDATE with in-set condition?

Tags: postgresql, locking

Does Postgresql apply the same type of locks on `UPDATE` with a range condition and on `UPDATE` with in-set condition?

E.g. will the queries:

1. `UPDATE table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);`
2. `UPDATE table WHERE id >= 1 AND id < 11`;

Cause the same type of locks on `table`?

Comment: Both will only lock the rows that are changed. The table itself will only be locked to prevent DDL statements against it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both statements will take a `UPDATE` lock on all the modified rows.

See [the documentation on row locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS):

> The `FOR UPDATE` lock mode is also acquired by any `DELETE` on a row, and also by an `UPDATE` that modifies the values on certain columns.